# Java GUI refresh results after opening file

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser, jformattedtextfield

I am trying to make an Income Tax Calculator and i have a `MainWindow` with a menu bar to open a file. After i open with `JFileChooser` and parse the file i put the results in a `Taxpayer` class. The problem is that is read the file but i can't make the results appear to the `MainWindow`. I somehow need to get back to the `MainWindow` and refresh the results after opening the file. So, basically what i need to do is to refresh the already opened `MainWindow`(which has empty JFormattedTextFields) with the appropriate infos to the `JFormattedTextField`.

Here's the code for the `MainWindow`:

```
package gui;

import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JMenu;

import javax.swing.JLabel;

import java.awt.Font;

import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JSeparator;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField;

import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.text.NumberFormatter;

import datamodel.Taxpayer;

public class MainWindow extends JFrame{

    private JFrame frame;
    private Taxpayer taxpayer;


    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    MainWindow window = new MainWindow();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);                  
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public MainWindow() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 590, 524);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle("Income Tax Calculator");

        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        JMenu menuFile = new JMenu("File");
        menuBar.add(menuFile);

        JMenuItem menuOpenFile = new JMenuItem("Open File");
        menuOpenFile.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                FileChooser chooser = new FileChooser();
                chooser.setVisible(true);       

            }
        });
        menuFile.add(menuOpenFile);

        JMenuItem menuExit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
        menuExit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                frame.dispose();
            }
        });
        menuFile.add(menuExit);

        JMenu menuOptions = new JMenu("Options");
        menuBar.add(menuOptions);

        JMenu menuTaxpayer = new JMenu("Taxpayer");
        menuOptions.add(menuTaxpayer);

        JMenuItem menuItemDeleteTaxpayer = new JMenuItem("Delete");
        menuItemDeleteTaxpayer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                TaxpayerDeletion deletedTaxpayer = new TaxpayerDeletion();
                deletedTaxpayer.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        menuTaxpayer.add(menuItemDeleteTaxpayer);

        JMenu menuReceipt = new JMenu("Receipt");
        menuOptions.add(menuReceipt);

        JMenuItem menuItemAdd = new JMenuItem("Add");
        menuItemAdd.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                ReceiptAdding receipt = new ReceiptAdding();
                receipt.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        menuReceipt.add(menuItemAdd);

        JMenuItem menuItemDeleteReceipt = new JMenuItem("Delete");
        menuItemDeleteReceipt.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                ReceiptDeletion deletedReceipt = new ReceiptDeletion();
                deletedReceipt.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        menuReceipt.add(menuItemDeleteReceipt);

        JMenu menuHelp = new JMenu("Help");
        menuBar.add(menuHelp);

        JMenuItem menuItemHelp = new JMenuItem("Help");
        menuHelp.add(menuItemHelp);

        JMenuItem menuItemAbout = new JMenuItem("About");
        menuHelp.add(menuItemAbout);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JLabel labelSelectTaxpayer = new JLabel("Please select a taxpayer from the list:");
        labelSelectTaxpayer.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        labelSelectTaxpayer.setBounds(25, 21, 211, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(labelSelectTaxpayer);

        JLabel labelPersonalDetails = new JLabel("Personal Details");
        labelPersonalDetails.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
        labelPersonalDetails.setBounds(238, 69, 211, 14);
        frame.getContentPane().add(labelPersonalDetails);

        JLabel labelName = new JLabel("Name:");
        labelName.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        labelName.setBounds(56, 105, 46, 14);
        frame.getContentPane().add(labelName);

        JLabel labelAfm = new JLabel("AFM:");
        labelAfm.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        labelAfm.setBounds(56, 130, 46, 14);
        frame.getContentPane().add(labelAfm);

        JLabel labelStatus = new JLabel("Status:");
        labelStatus.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        labelStatus.setBounds(56, 155, 46, 14);
        frame.getContentPane().add(labelStatus);

        JLabel labelIncome = new JLabel("Income:");
        labelIncome.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        labelIncome.setBounds(56, 180, 59, 14);
        frame.getContentPane().add(labelIncome);

        JLabel labelReceipts = new JLabel("Receipts:");
        labelReceipts.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        labelReceipts.setBounds(56, 205, 59, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(labelReceipts);

        JButton buttonCalculate = new JButton("Calculate");
        buttonCalculate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                Report report = new Report();
                report.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        buttonCalculate.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
        buttonCalculate.setBounds(429, 425, 135, 31);
        frame.getContentPane().add(buttonCalculate);

        JSeparator separatorLeftDetails = new JSeparator();
        separatorLeftDetails.setBounds(10, 81, 218, 2);
        frame.getContentPane().add(separatorLeftDetails);

        JSeparator separatorRightDetails = new JSeparator();
        separatorRightDetails.setBounds(346, 81, 219, 2);
        frame.getContentPane().add(separatorRightDetails);

        JComboBox comboBoxTaxpayerList = new JComboBox();
        comboBoxTaxpayerList.setBounds(246, 23, 319, 20);
        frame.getContentPane().add(comboBoxTaxpayerList);

        JComboBox comboBoxReceiptsList = new JComboBox();
        comboBoxReceiptsList.setBounds(143, 207, 357, 20);
        frame.getContentPane().add(comboBoxReceiptsList);


        JFormattedTextField formattedTextFieldAfm = new JFormattedTextField();
        formattedTextFieldAfm.setEditable(false);
        formattedTextFieldAfm.setEnabled(true);
        if(taxpayer != null){
            System.out.println("TAXPAYER NOT NULL");
            formattedTextFieldAfm.setText(String.valueOf(taxpayer.getTaxRegistrationNumber()));
            formattedTextFieldAfm.setVisible(true);
        }

        formattedTextFieldAfm.setBounds(143, 128, 357, 20);
        frame.getContentPane().add(formattedTextFieldAfm);

        JFormattedTextField formattedTextFieldStatus = new JFormattedTextField();
        formattedTextFieldStatus.setEditable(false);
        formattedTextFieldStatus.setEnabled(true);
        if(taxpayer != null){
            formattedTextFieldStatus.setText(taxpayer.getStatus());
        }

        formattedTextFieldStatus.setBounds(143, 153, 357, 20);
        frame.getContentPane().add(formattedTextFieldStatus);

        JFormattedTextField formattedTextFieldIncome = new JFormattedTextField();
        formattedTextFieldIncome.setEditable(false);
        formattedTextFieldIncome.setEnabled(true);
        //formattedTextFieldIncome.setText(String.valueOf(taxpayer.getIncome()));
        formattedTextFieldIncome.setBounds(143, 178, 357, 20);
        frame.getContentPane().add(formattedTextFieldIncome);

        JFormattedTextField formattedTextFieldName = new JFormattedTextField();
        formattedTextFieldName.setEditable(false);
        formattedTextFieldName.setEnabled(true);
        //formattedTextFieldName.setText(taxpayer.getName());
        formattedTextFieldName.setBounds(143, 103, 357, 20);
        frame.getContentPane().add(formattedTextFieldName);

        JSeparator separatorLeftCalculation = new JSeparator();
        separatorLeftCalculation.setBounds(10, 253, 218, 2);
        frame.getContentPane().add(separatorLeftCalculation);

        JLabel lblTaxCalculation = new JLabel("Tax Calculation");
        lblTaxCalculation.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
        lblTaxCalculation.setBounds(233, 227, 200, 50);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblTaxCalculation);

        JSeparator separatorReightCalculation = new JSeparator();
        separatorReightCalculation.setBounds(340, 253, 225, 2);
        frame.getContentPane().add(separatorReightCalculation);

        JLabel lblPleaseSelectOne = new JLabel("Please select one or more options for tax calculation");
        lblPleaseSelectOne.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        lblPleaseSelectOne.setBounds(155, 266, 505, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblPleaseSelectOne);

        JCheckBox checkBoxTotalTax = new JCheckBox("Total Tax");
        checkBoxTotalTax.setBounds(93, 306, 150, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(checkBoxTotalTax);

        JCheckBox chechBoxTaxAnalysis = new JCheckBox("Tax analysis(Basic tax, tax increase or decrease based on receipts)");
        chechBoxTaxAnalysis.setBounds(92, 332, 357, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(chechBoxTaxAnalysis);

        JCheckBox checkBoxReceiptsTotalValue = new JCheckBox("Total value of the gathered receipts");
        checkBoxReceiptsTotalValue.setBounds(93, 358, 271, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(checkBoxReceiptsTotalValue);

        JCheckBox checkBoxAmountDifferentCategories = new JCheckBox("Analysis of the amounts spent for different categories of expenditure");
        checkBoxAmountDifferentCategories.setBounds(93, 384, 421, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(checkBoxAmountDifferentCategories);


    }

    public void setTaxpayerInfo(Taxpayer taxpayer){
        this.taxpayer = taxpayer;
        System.out.println("Test message :Inside");
    }
}
```

And this is the code for `FileChooser`:

```
package gui;


import input.TxtParser;

import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;








import datamodel.Taxpayer;

import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class FileChooser extends JFrame {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private Taxpayer taxpayer;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    FileChooser frame = new FileChooser();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public FileChooser() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 593, 436);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        javax.swing.JFileChooser fileChooser = new javax.swing.JFileChooser();
        fileChooser.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(e.getActionCommand()!= null){
                    File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
                    TxtParser txtParser = new TxtParser();

                        try {
                            taxpayer = txtParser.parse(file);
                            if(taxpayer == null){
                                System.out.println("NULL TAXPAYER");
                            }
                            System.out.println(taxpayer);
                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
                    mainWindow.setTaxpayerInfo(taxpayer);
                    mainWindow.setEnabled(true);
                    mainWindow.setVisible(true);

                    close();
                }
            }
        });
        fileChooser.setBounds(0, 0, 582, 397);
        contentPane.add(fileChooser);
        this.setTitle("Income Tax Calculator");
    }



    private void close(){
        this.dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a lot of code to go through, could you please shorten this to a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/mcve)?

Comment: Your extending from `JFrame`, but making a new instance of a `JFrame` which is independent of the `MainWindow` instance, no wonder you're confused.  The `FileChoooser` class is, frankly unnessacery, it could simply be achieved within the `ActionListener` and using `JFileChooser` class (which has it's own dialog)

Comment: Isolate the areas of responsibility to make it easier to confine and control the logic you are trying to apply

Comment: So, should i remove the `FileChooser` class and do the job inside `MainWindow`? and then how can i update the `JFormattedTextFields` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a number of issues...

First, your `MainWindow` class extend from `JFrame`, but also create another instance of `JFrame`

```
public class MainWindow extends JFrame{

    private JFrame frame;
```

Which frame is actually the one which contains the content or is visible on the screen?  I'd start by removing `extends JFrame`

The `FileChooser` class is just not required, you're duplicating functionality which is provided by the `JFileChooser` class itself and making your life hard by doing it...

```
JMenuItem menuOpenFile = new JMenuItem("Open File");
menuOpenFile.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        switch (chooser.showOpenDialog(frame)) {
        case JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION:
            File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
            TxtParser txtParser = new TxtParser();

            try {
            taxpayer = txtParser.parse(file);
            if (taxpayer == null) {
                System.out.println("NULL TAXPAYER");
            }
            System.out.println(taxpayer);
            setTextpayerInfo(taxPayer);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
        }
    }
});
```

In your existing `FileChooser` class, you create another instance of `MainWindow` and call `setTextpayerInfo`, but `setTextpayerInfo` doesn't do anything?!

Your `setTextpayerInfo` method needs to fill out the fields or controls which you want the user to be able to manipulate.

Separate you functionality into separate classes, so that you have, for example, a `TaxPayerPane`, which contains the fields and controls which directly relate to the management of the `TaxPayer` class.

Then combine the functionality you need (the menus) and the `TaxPayerPane` onto A single instance of `JFrame`.  Use setters/getters to pass information between the separate parts of the application as required.

The idea here is to separate and confine distinct parts of your application so that they are only doing the single job to which they are designed to.  This decouples your code, making it easier to manage and change and reduces the overlapping complexity of trying to manage diverse blocks of logic

Also, avoid `null` layouts, they are more of a headache then they are worth.  Making use of appropriate layout managers, combining them to produce not only rich UIs but also flexible UIs which can adapt to the differences between platforms and look and feels

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is awnsered in a very practical form of coding : Model-View-Controler Design Patern. 
Take a look at the wiki : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller

On the other hand if you want a fast way to do this, and it is NOT the best way, you can consider passing your MainWindow to the taxPayer class where you would change you fields to global variables and change them.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Your verging on attracting down votes for suggesting things like "global variables" which will only get the OP into more trouble and have us doing more work to untangle it.

Comment: Yeah i just wanted to make it easy for him if he needs a "fast solution". Iclearly state it is Not the way you want to do this. but if he has no time learning MVC....

Comment: IMHO SO is suppose to be a forum where professionals can get professional advice to problems they are having. Providing "short-cuts" doesn't help the OP nor anybody else who might be having a similar problem, now is a good time (and a greater opportunity) to teach the OP about good practices, sure, it might take a little more time now, but will save a enormous amount of time in the future.  Perfect practice makes perfect (and yes, I have a hard time sometimes maintaining that level to)